# measure executing time of command line calls

Tags: ruby

I am writing a Ruby 1.9.2 script for evaluating the execution times of different external command line calls.

I used the ruby Process.system method to execute the command line calls and tried to capture the executing time as follows:

```
start = Time.now
system("./script1", "argX")

puts "Duration: #{Time.now - start} seconds"
```

Now I have the problem that the duration doesn't reflect the execution time of the external process but the execution time of the "system" call.

Any idea how I can measure the execution time of the external process?

Answer (score 13):

Okay. If I understand what you are trying to do, you want to time how long the "./script1" call takes to run?

One thing you might want to do is to use the [benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) library (it's standard).

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm (7) do |x|
  x.report ("script1:") {system("./script1", "argX")}
end
```

That will generate a report with user and system times, which may be what you want.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken using the benchmark library in this way will still include the time it takes for the system command to be run.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `time` and parse the results

```
require 'open3'

command = './script1 argX'

stdout,stderr,status = Open3.capture3("time #{command}")

results = {}
stderr.split("\n").each do |line|
  unless line.blank?
    result_type,result = line.split("\t")
    results[result_type] = result
  end
end
puts "Clock time was #{results['real']}"
```

`time` outputs a format like

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s
```

And it outputs it to the *the standard error*, which is why we need to use `Open3` to get it (and differentiate it from the output of your script, which hopefully will not clash with `time`'s output).

Note that time has a "formatted" output for the time elapsed, so you may need to do some parsing to get this into a raw milliseconds format.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to time the Ruby-process executing your script. When you're working on a *nix system you can use the `time` utility. You can then do the following: `time ruby *yourscript*`

Comment: macs are *nix systems haha